# How does "living in this country" modify both "men" and "women" in this sentence?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrases

> The wisdom of men and the beauty of women living in this country are both remarkable.

Can "living in this country" modify "men" in this sentence? I believe "living in this country" could modify the noun or noun phrase before it. So in this sentence, the nouns (noun phrases) modified by "living in this country" are only 3 possibilities:

1. [(women)(living in this country)]
2. [(the beauty of women)(living in this country)]
3. [(The wisdom of men and the beauty of women)(living in this country)]

For 1, it only modifies "women", while 2 and 3 apparently make no sense.
To allow "living in this country" modify both "men" and "women", I think the original sentence should be seen as an omitting version of

> The wisdom of men (living in this country) and the beauty of women living in this country are both remarkable.

Is my explanation reasonable or not?

Comment: Punctuation is the key to your problem.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Sorry, but I don't get your points well.

Comment: _Both_ implies that two things are being called remarkable. Common sense suggests that it doesn't mean 'the wisdom of men in general'.

Comment: I don't understand why you say 2 and 3 "make no sense." I agree it's confusing, but not nonsensical

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Because I think, in 2 and 3, the logical subjects of "living" are "the beauty" and"the wisdom and the beauty"(here I omit the modifying part "of men/women"), which makes no sense, right? After all, it's human beings who could live in a country, not "wisdom" nor "beauty".

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I mean it may be grammatically correct, but it doesn't make sense semantically.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean.

Comment: Part of what makes the sentence incongruous is its implied sexism. Are the women foolish, and the men ugly?

Comment: reminds me of Lake Wobegon, “where all the women are strong, all the men are good-looking, and all the children are above average.”

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty We have no idea where this example sentence came from or why it's worded the way it is, and the way it's worded regarding men and women has nothing to do with the question being asked. If there's implied sexism, it's because you're judging it to be that way outside of all context and without any purpose relating to the question. It really isn't necessary to pick a fight... and if for some reason it is, it's highly unlikely the fight is with this OP.

Comment: @JBH  The sentence, its meaning and structure, are what they are, regardless its source, and it was that on which I commented. As to picking a fight, follow your own advice.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Perhaps you've missed the point of my courtesy. Unless you're godlike, you have no idea what that sentence's purpose is or even if it's sexist at all. You're assuming it's offensive and that the allegedly offensive nature is fundamental to the question. This fight is worth picking because I believe that choice is a CoC violation. Especially here on [ell.se], the OP deserves the benefit of the doubt. With that I'll leave you with the last word if you wish it.

Comment: @JBH You have misinterpreted my comment to be about offensiveness. It was about the comprehensibility of the sentence as posted, regardless who composed it. Enough, already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your explanation is reasonable**

The sentence isn't a great sentence, but it would be one I believe commonly used here in the western United States. To make the sentence grammatically "perfect" (if such a word can ever be applied to grammar) we need to add a few things.

> The wisdom of the men who live in this country and the beauty of the women who live in this country are both remarkable.

Language, especially spoken language, tends to shorten obvious contextual associations. Wisdom can't live in a country. Neither can beauty. Thus "living in this country" can *contextually* only modify the words "men" and "women." Therefore, for this case, I would expect people to simplify the redundant use of "the [object] who live in this country" by using it only once and dropping the words "the" and "who" (the men who -> men, the women who -> women).

> The wisdom of **men** and the beauty of **women living in this country** are both remarkable.

Comment: why not: This country's wise men and beautiful women are both remarkable.

Comment: @BrianD That would work fine! My answer simply focused on the OP's original sentence structure to help the OP understand what that structure was doing. I mentioned that the original sentence structure "isn't a great sentence." Your version is absolutely more elegant.